# Phaser/Pixi Normal Map Filter Not Working

Tags: javascript, webgl, phaser-framework, pixi.js

I'm trying to apply a normal map to a Phaser sprite, but I'm getting the following WebGL errors in Phaser 2.1.1 (Pixi 1.6.1):

```
Could not initialise shaders phaser.js:3411
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid phaser.js:3475
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getUniformLocation: program not linked phaser.js:3478
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getAttribLocation: program not linked phaser.js:3486
```

Here is my code:

```
preload: function () {
  game.load.script('normal',   './js/NormalMapFilter.js');

  game.load.image('cardfront',  './img/sample-front.png');
  game.load.image('cardnormal', './img/sample-front-norm.jpg');
},

create: function() {
  this.cardfrontnorm = PIXI.Texture.fromImage('cardnormal');
  this.normalmap = new PIXI.NormalMapFilter(this.cardfrontnorm);

  this.card = game.add.sprite(game.width / 2, game.height / 2, 'cardfront');
  this.card.filters = [this.normalmap];
}
```

Both the sprite image and the normal map are 512x512.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you can post it on jsfiddle or similar, I'll check if I get the same error

Comment: @imcg Unfortunately, that's a bit difficult due to CORS restrictions and the assets being loaded via js.

Comment: I've got the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, NormalMapFilter was an experiment and never meant to be introduced into the library:

[Check HTML5 Game Devs - Pixijs forum](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/15638-im-having-a-hell-of-a-time-trying-to-get-normalmapfilter-to-work/?hl=normal#entry88695)

However, you can try to use a plugin for lighting here:
https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-lights